# Text Box Height & Width

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, textbox

How can do you convert Microsoft Access Height & Width to a C# WinForm Height & Width?  For example, I want Width 5.1667" & Height 1.667" (access) to a C# Windows Form Text Box.  But if I attempt to input those figures into a C# Windows Form Height/Width property they are 1st invalid, so if I change the width to 5 it is considerably to small to enter data into...

What is the conversion method to convert that access text box size to a C# windows form size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float accesswidth = 5.1667f;
float accessheight = 1.667f;
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
float csharpwidth = accesswidth * graphics.DpiX;
float csharpheight = accessheight * graphics.DpiY;
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("width: {0}, height: {1}", 
                               csharpwidth.ToString(),
                               csharpheight.ToString()));
```

Comment: in what format would I input the accesssize?  Is that height or width or both?